# how to show or hide an input depending on the option selected in an input select?

Tags: vue.js

I need an input to be shown when selecting option 2 in a selector, I am new in vue and I don't know very well how to do it. I don't know if I have to capture the value with an onchange or there is another way to do it? In the v-model I show the data that come from the database since it is a form that can be edited and the inputs have to appear filled according to the field of the table that we want to edit.

```
         <v-tab-item value="access">
                          <v-form ref="form">
                                <v-row style="margin-top: 20px;" >
                                    <v-col cols="12">                
                                        <v-select 
                                          v-model="data.accessType"
                                          :items="accessTypes"
                                          v-bind:value="accessTypes.id"
                                          item-text="name"
                                          item-value="id"
                                          menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                          :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.access-type_placeholder')"    
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col cols="12" v-if="accessTypes.id == 2">
                                          <v-select 
                                             chips
                                             multiple
                                             v-model="data.workplaces"
                                             :items="data.name"
                                             item-text="name"
                                             item-value="id"
                                             menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                             :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.workplaces')"
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col cols="12">
                                          <v-select
                                             chips
                                             multiple
                                             v-model="data.departments"
                                             :items="data.departments"
                                             item-text="name"
                                             item-value="id"
                                             menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                             :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.departments')"
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                       <v-col cols="12">
                                          <v-select
                                             chips
                                             multiple
                                             v-model="data.projects"
                                             :items="data.projects"
                                             item-text="name"
                                             item-value="id"
                                             menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                             :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.projects')"
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col cols="12">                
                                          <v-text-field
                                              v-model="data.employees"
                                              :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.access-type_employees')"
                                              autocomplete="none"
                                              :rules="[validationRules.required]"
                                              max="400"
                                          />
                                      </v-col>
                                </v-row>
                           </v-form>
                        </v-tab-item>

  data() {
      return {
         showDialog: false,
         loading: true,
         tab: 0,
         data: {},
       
         accessTypes: [{id:1, name:'Toda la empresa'},
                           {id:2, name:'Un grupo concreto'},
                           {id:3, name:'Equipos o proyectos'},
                           {id:4, name:'Trabajadores concretos'},
                            {id:5, name:'Script'}
                           ],
      }
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use v-model - [Form Input Select](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#select)

```js
<script setup>
const selected = ref('')
</script>
<template>
<div v-show="selected == 'B'">
  This will be shown only if you select option B
</div>
<div v-if="selected == 'B'">
  The same, but the element gets removed
  from the page if selected is not B, instead of simply hidden
</div>

<select v-model="selected" multiple>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
</template>
```

Comment: I get an error that the variable is defined but not used.

Comment: Which variable? In my code I declare only “selected”, and it’s used.